# Manage conflicting roles in chef

Tags: conflict, roles, chef-infra

I am relatively new to chef, so I may be missing something extremely basic. After much searching I am not finding what I need, so here goes:

In Chef, I have roles that are conflicting. I need for all servers of a certain type to have roleA, except for servers with roleB.

The best way I can think of to describe it is with an example:

syslog1, syslog2

web1, web2, web3

db1, db2

mail1, mail2

Every server within this environment(dozens) has a role called syslog_client, except syslog1 and syslog2, which need to have the role syslog_server.

The syslog-server and syslog-client roles conflict, because they configure the same pieces of software differently.

These are roles rather than recipes because they actually encompass several recipes.

I thought of doing something like this:

roles/base.rb:

```
name "base"
description "base configuration"
override_attributes(
)
default_attributes(
)
run_list(
  "recipe[one]",
  "recipe[two]",
  "recipe[three]",
  "role[uno]"
)

unless node[:roles].include?('syslog_server')
  run_list('role[syslog_client]')
end
```

The problem there is that the node object does not exist at this point. I have thought about moving it into the recipe, but I could not come up with a good way to do it there either. I was able to use this in the base recipe:

```
unless node[:roles].include?('syslog_server')
  node[:roles]+=['syslog_client']
end
```

This adds syslog_client to the roles attribute (or doesn't) correctly, but it never actually runs the syslog_client role.

I have considered moving syslog_client into a self-contained recipe rather than a role, and moving the role attributes to the environment. This would work, because then I can just call `include_recipe "syslog::client"`. The problem there is that virtually all of our recipes are assigned from roles (not from other recipes), and I fear that making this change will create a one-off that will be hard to keep track of. Besides that, as I mentioned already, these are actually several recipes, so adding them as a single recipe is not ideal.

We have many different server types/roles in the environment I'm currently working in, and adding role[syslog_client] to them is feasible, but not ideal. With multiple people working on this, it seems likely that someone will forget to add the recipe to a new role.

In an ideal world, something like my first solution would be possible, because that allows us to keep our environment as consistent as possible. I am open to other options though.

So to wrap up, I think what I need is someone to tell me how to:

1. Make the first solution work. Add a role to a run list only if another role is not present
2. If I cannot have #1, I'd like opinions on the best way to achieve this using the ways I've listed or other ideas I have not thought of

Please let me know if I'm missing any details about our chef setup that will be helpful.

**Disclaimer**: The above example is really a very simplified version of what I'm actually trying to achieve. I'm not even working with syslog, but the company it is for is very security-conscious and would not be happy with details of their environment being posted publicly. I will be as detailed as I possibly can if I've left anything out and I need to add further info.

Comment: Hey ben, maybe I'm confused on your setup but why dont you have a separate server role that is applied to those two nodes that doesn't call syslog_client? If you had a client and server role separate, you could start by specifying the syslog role and then the rest of the required recipes. I guess I don't understand how you have conflicts unless you are trying to lump stuff into one role.

Comment: That is precisely the problem. This role is the "base" role which is applied to all servers. It configures users, some basic environment stuff on the server, etc. By adding syslog_client to the base role, we are able to ensure every server gets the syslog_client. But I want to be able to tell the syslog_server role to negate the syslog_client role.

Comment: Is there any other stuff in the base role that is common to both servers and clients? I guess I would just have a base role for anything you need on everything and then call a server or client role after that. Essentially add another role level between base and any node-specific config. Sorry if I'm missing a distinction you are making.

Comment: Yes, the base role contains many configuration items, that EVERY server gets. This is a design decision (not made by me) that is already in use across several production clusters in multiple datacenters, and would be very hard to change. The idea here is to include the syslog_client role within the base role (since it will go on all but 1% of the servers), then negate the syslog_client role if the syslog_server role is in the run_list. I realize that there are alternative design choices, but keeping with the fundamental design is important to the company.

Comment: If you add a syslog_server role into run_list after the syslog_client role, then the syslog_server will overwrite the configuration provided by syslog_client.

Comment: This would be the case if the configurations were similar at all, but they are not. The syslog example I gave doesn't really explain the problem, but in keeping with the same example, imagine that syslog was just a shell program that runs any modules installed. Since syslog_server installs server_module1 and server_module2, and syslog_client installs client_module1 and client_module2, when you try to start syslog it tries to run syslog_client and syslog_server modules, causing issues.

Comment: Then syslog_server recipe should undo the syslog_client recipe by deleting the installed modules, configurations and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending what was said above what's the issue with creating two roles. A Client and a server

The Client role includes the base role and the client function. It will get applied to all servers through replacing references to 'base' with this role in all other roles. Meaning those roles still get base but get client as well.

The server is a stand-alone role which only applies to those servers and has the base and then the server role?

That way both client and server get the base role applied to them without duplicating the definition of what the base role is. You still manage that base role as you want but you use aggregation in the creation of roles?

When a new role is created the user won't start by adding base but instead adding the syslog_client role which gives them base as well.

To me that feels like the way Chef is pushing you with the creation of roles. What we have is 1 role that applies to all servers, some that apply to 1 subtype of servers but not anothers. That way our leaf role as in the one that gets applied actually consists of 4 or 5 other roles. What's common is modelled in a way that can be shared without the need for logic within?

The other option would be to add the client recipe to every node and the first exeuction step is to check the nodes role and if it says server just basically skip the recipe execution? Which would be the same as the logic which you were wanting to use to add the recipe but it would live in the recipe and control the execution?

```
unless node[:roles].include?('syslog_server')
   #Do your client install
end
```

Comment: This is essentially what I did:
`unless node[:roles].include?('syslog_server')`

I am not happy with this solution, and it has already led to confusion, but I had to move on from this issue and this was the best I could do in the time allotted. I've accepted your answer since I never came back to post it myself. Thanks for the suggestions